# Nunit-Console: Is there any way to use Test Selection Language with Command Line options

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-console

I am trying to run Specific test cases using nunit console runner with the following command

```
nunit-console.exe \run:Namespace TestDll.dll --where "method=Methodname1 || Methodname2"
```

But this doesnt work.Im using Nunit 2.6.x .

Please help

Comment: [Test selection language](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Selection-Language) isn't fully supported in NUnit V2, only `test` and `cat` are supported, as documentation says. Try to use V3

Comment: TSL is used with the `--where` option, which is a feature of NUnit 3 and doesn't even partially exist in V2. You should use the docs for the version of NUnit you are using. See https://nunit.org/documentation/